# Getting undesired result while using $set in mongodb with string containing period

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an object stored in my collection in mongodb

```
{
  "students" : {
    "abc@gmail.com" : {"gender" : "M", "marks" : 30},
    "xyz@gmail.com" : {"gender" : "M", "marks" : 40}
  }
}
```

I am trying to update the marks for the student with the id "xyz@gmail.com" using the following code snippet:

```
db.getCollection('school').updateOne(
    {
        $set:{
            "students.xyz@gmail.com": {
                "gender":"M",
                "marks": 40
            }
        }
    }
)
```

But instead of updating the existing record, it is creating a new object like this:

```
{
  "students" : {
    "abc@gmail.com" : {"gender" : "M", "marks" : 30},
    "xyz@gmail.com" : {"gender" : "M", "marks" : 40},
    "xyz@gmail" : {"com" : {"gender" : "M", "marks" : 40}}
  }
}
```

So, this is happening because of the `.` in the email id, in the `.com`.
Is there a way mongodb handle this ?

Comment: Field names are referenced using a dotted notation.  In the $set clause, you are expecting the database to consider the first dot a field separator, but consider the second one to be part of the field name.  It is best to avoid field names that contain '$' or '.' for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm putting this in an answer as it won't all fit in the comments.

I would encourage you to please read [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#field-names-with-periods--.--and-dollar-signs----).

If you continue with using dots in the key then you are going to find it difficult to do updates and will hit so many issues in your application.

My advice would be to change, if you can, the structure to something like this:

```js
{
  students : [
    {email: "abc@gmail.com", gender: "M", marks: 30},
    {email: "xyz@gmail.com", gender: "M", marks: 40}
  ]
}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```js
db.getCollection('school').updateOne({students: {$elemMatch: {email:'xyz@gmail.com'}}},
    {
        $set: {
            "students.$": {
                "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
                "gender":"M",
                "marks": 100
            }
        }
    }
);
```